# SQL server 2008 "row updated" timestamp

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to extract a row updated time stamp from SQL Server 2008? Maybe by interrogating the log file?

Comment: Does your table have a DateTime that is updated with the row or a TimeStamp column? Do you need a meaningful date and time or are you just trying to establish whether the row has been updated?

Comment: No there is no date column. I need to know when the row was modified. Is there any way to interrogate the sql log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've not added a column yourself to record when a row has been updated, you'll have to go for software that can view the transaction log such as [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) or [Quest's LiteSpeed For SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/)